# MS Word 2010: Hide citation title when 2 publications by same first author from different years are in one citation block

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, citations

I'm trying to hide the display of the titles for two publications by the same first author from different years that are in the same citation block. By default, the title is shown in citations when there are two publications by the same author in a given document.

The easiest way to get around this is to right click on the citation, click "Edit Citation", and then suppress the title. However, the issue with this is that if there are 2 citations in 1 citation block (i.e., "(Smith, J., et al. 2010, Smith, J., et al. 2011)" rather than "(Smith, J., et al. 2010) (Smith, J., et al. 2011)"), then using that suppress option only suppresses the title for the first citation (in this case, the 2010 publication).

OTOH, if I try to initially insert the publications in separate citation blocks, I can suppress the title in both citations, but I can't cut and paste one into the other's citation block. I can click "Cut" and the citation that was just cut disappears, but the "Paste" option is not available when my cursor is in the second citation block.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but as it's still a relatively high result in Google, and I recently struggled with this in my thesis, I thought it's worth posting the solution here for reference.

The solution is to right click on the citation, and select "Edit Field".  For a citation block with multiple citations, the field code will resemble:

```
CITATION Peisert2008 \l 2057  \m Erbacher2010
```

To suppress the title for a citation, append `\t` after the key for the paper.  So, to suppress a single title in the previous example, I could modify the field code to:

```
CITATION Peisert2008 \t \l 2057  \m Erbacher2010
```

And to suppress both titles, it would be sufficient to modify the code to:

```
CITATION Peisert2008 \t \l 2057  \m Erbacher2010 \t
```

Obviously, this solution will work for an arbitrary number of citations in a single block.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2010/09/22/mla-apa-chicago-microsoft-word-formats-bibliographies-for-you/) it is a known bug, carried on to Word 2013 as well.

However, there is an easy workaround:

1. Click on citation.
2. Choose "Edit Citation".
3. Click the "Title" checkbox (under the "Suppress" section).

For detailed screenshots, see the mentioned [blog](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2010/09/22/mla-apa-chicago-microsoft-word-formats-bibliographies-for-you/).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Good answer, thank you. If you look at the field codes when you suppress title, name or year, you'll see \t \n \y in the field codes. So kudos to Brett as well. However one thing to note is that if you use the suppress check boxes approach, it only adds the \t switch to the first citation. The others (assuming there are others in the field) may still have titles. So best practice for citation fields with multiple citations and unwanted titles in the second or third etc. field is to edit the field codes and add the \t switch.

I would suggest, however, that this is not a "bug" but a style convention. It's just a bit annoying since you'd hope papers from the same set of authors would be differentiated by year (and at worst, 2008a and 2008b) but oh well. This works!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).